# KDE session not start

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, screen

I have been using KDE in Ubuntu 18.04 since the first week after its release. Since last Friday I am unable to login to my account using KDE. Just the mouse pointer is shown on a black screen.

However, I can start a GNOME/Ubuntu session with no problems.

I thought something was corrupted in one of .kde files and so I created a new user for test purposes.

With this new test user the same happens. After typing the password, and clicking on the login button, the default background with no icons is displayed for a moment, and then there is just a black screen with the mouse pointer on it.

Pressing CTRL-ALT-DEL causes the logout screen to appear.  I then can close the current session and go back to the login screen. The same happens from my regular user running a Gnome session and then switching to this test user.

The system is updated. I have had no problems recently with power outages, file system corruption, or anything else that I can remember.

I would appreciate any ideas and possible solutions to test.

The .xsession-errors can be found in the next 24h here: https://a.uguu.se/WiffLehggjqz_tst.xsession-errors

(Do you know a better way to share a large file like this to anonymous people, no specific recipient ?  Please let me know.)

Comment: If you install two desktop environments on the same machine, some odd behavior is possible.

Comment: It is not the case. It was working fine since the first week in May. Although, a new user, with a clean environment, should be not affected by any kind of conflicts between 2 desktops.